# getting facebook inbox messages in other sites

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-messages

I am building a small personal homepage, and I wanted to get all my Facebook inbox messages there, instead of having to go to Facebook to read them. So, I searched for API all over the developers.facebook.com but I am not sure if this type of API exists.

I have checked several questions like this one [getting inbox message via facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175228/getting-inbox-message-via-facebook-api)

but they are either un answered or some answers when I copy/paste that did not work out at all

Comment: Already answered by @Thomas David Plat, you can check https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Finbox to get your messages, this will require extended permission read_mailbox

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with an authenticated user with the `read_mailbox` permission. You can then make a graph API call like this:

`me/inbox`

to retrieve an users inbox.

If you're using the PHP SDK you can call:

`$facebook->api('me/inbox');`

You might want to have a look on this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: So how do I install that link ?

Comment: I never heard that links can be installed. You need a basic understanding of the facebook Graph API and the authentication flow. That would be too broad to answer here. Check the Graph API docs ;)

Comment: I meant, how do I install the application or the SDK so facebook can allow me to access the the API. Because, I know the code you have given me does not work as is.